# How to refresh JWT token when App launches

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to login user automatically if refresh_token exists in localStorage  but my issue here is, i am not able to change state to authenticated initially when app start. I tried with componentWillMount but i am getting old state 1st time then i get updated state. `<PrivateRoute>` here getting called 2-3 time, don't know where i am making mistake.

Expected Flow

- autoLogin
- PrivateRoute with new state

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import WrappedLoginForm from './containers/Login'
import ChatApp from './containers/Chat'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { checkAuthentication } from './store/actions/auth'
import PrivateRoute from './route'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.autoLogin()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Route path='/login' component={WrappedLoginForm} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ChatApp} authed={this.props.isAuthenticated} />
            </Router>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        loading: state.loading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        autoLogin: () => {
            dispatch(checkAuthentication())
        }
    }
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

**route.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => {
  console.log('aaa')
  return (<Route
    render={props => (
      authed
        ? <Component />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />
    )}
  />)
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**action.js**

```
export const checkAuthentication = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authStart())

        let refresh_token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
        axiosInstance.post('/api/token/refresh/', {
            refresh: refresh_token
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200)  {
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access)
                dispatch(loginSuccess())
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("balle")
            dispatch(loginFailed(error))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you put your authentication checking code inside of componentDidMount() instead? Curious if it still gets stale values

Comment: Same thing...in that case PrivateRouter called first with old state then code inside componentDidMount get called but result is same

Answer (score 0):

first thing make sure that in your store the isAuthenticated property is false by default.

For PrivateRoute use :

```
{this.props.isAuthenticated
        ?  <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ChatApp} />
        : null
}
```

instead of  `<PrivateRoute path="/" component={ChatApp} authed={this.props.isAuthenticated} />`